# linking static library into dll

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, static-libraries

In windows programing, 
If you have a static library which is intended to be linked with a dll library where the dll has /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS defined, then which of the following marcos should be defined in static library?

```
_LIB
_WINDOWS
```

I'm confusing these macros because a static library it self will never show it's own window or console on it's own, so I can't understatnd why do we need to define these macros for static library project?

Comment: My guess is that `_LIB` is so you can tell you're building a library, and `_WINDOWS` is because you're on the *Windows* platform. Macros such as these are commonly used for conditional compilation, so you can have different code on different platforms for example.

Comment: you're right about _LIB, but _WINDOWS means that subsystem is windows, _WIN32(always defined) indicates a platform, but I don't understand why do we need to define _WINDOWS macro for static lib if dll has windows subsystem?

Comment: Subsystem (CONSOLE OR WINDOWS) is only meaningful for an executable. It is ignored for a DLL.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for your input, can you please back up your claim by providing some reference because according to visual studio project template,(creating a project) a subsystem is defined even for DLL's? also I've read and tested this: http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/felxible-dllstatic-library-linkage-configurations/

Comment: The PE executable headers always specify the subsystem. But it only has impact for executable. It's how the loader decides whether to make a console or not when starting the process. Imagine if calling `LoadLibrary` from a GUI process to load a DLL with CONSOLE subsystem suddenly changed your process to be a console app. Or imagine if you wanted to load the same DLL in both console and GUI apps. A good example might be kernel32.dll. What subsystem is it?

Comment: these things are out of my area but I see now, so I'm guessing a kernel32.dll is of subsystem WINDOWS? if so how do you call it then from console application? thanks :)

Comment: As I already said twice, the subsystem of a PE module is only meaningful for an executable. And FWIW, dumpbin reports that kernel32, on my system at least, has subsystem 3 (Windows CUI), that is console.

Comment: Oh, thanks!! I voted up your valuable comments.

Comment: Anyway, what are `_LIB` and `_WINDOWS`? Are they private to the library?

Comment: no, I need to define these because I downloaded some old VS projects which are missing these default macros, because these macros are only created during a project creation and not updated when modifiying a project output.

Comment: So, why does the code object if you don't define `_WINDOWS`?

Comment: hm, I didn't test for _WINDOWS macro but removing _CONSOLE marco and not defining a subsystem opens a console anyway. I'm gonna create a window and see what would happen if removing a /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS ^^ you are driving me around, thank you but maybe you can spare some time writing a good answer so I could finaly understand all this :)

Comment: Are you building a DLL or an executable?

Comment: I have a solution of depended pojects that consist of static library, dll, and console applications. there are also other solutions with window applications dll's and static libraries as well. they all depend on each other, so I'm trying not to mess with CRT and subsystem to make them all compatible, it's a GTK+ stack in short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few points:

- It's entirely possible for functions in a static library to create and manipulate UI, either User32 windows or console (I guess Modern UI as well).
- Unless you provide special functions for the purpose, the application using your library can't tell what macros were used for library compilation.
- Windows headers sometimes will provide defaults if you haven't defined any of a set of macros 
  (e.g. `WINVER`)
- These macros are only as magic as your code makes them.  If you aren't testing them, then defining them is going to have almost no effect.
- If your library does conditionally make UI features available, skipping those at compile-time with `#if defined(_WINDOWS)` has some advantages over run-time enable flags.

In particular, if calls to UI functions are stripped by the preprocessor, the linker won't need to add UI DLLs to the import table.  Might make a difference whether your library works on Server Core installs of Windows.  At the same time, runtime checks are nice because you only need to compile the library once and distribute one version.  Using run-time enable flags and setting the linker to use delay-load might give the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 1):

after fighting with google for houres and various forums and white papers I found out what all that means when using visual studio!

**static library:**
does not need an /ENTRY or /SUBSYSTEM because the code will be linked into another code.
so the library does not need a console, windnow or entry point

**dll:**
/SUBSYSTEM should be set to WINDOWS and /ENTRY should not be set, why?
no entry because in visual studio linker [automaticaly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) creates a DllMain entry point.
subsystem of dll should be set to WINDOWS [link1](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=1659.0) [link2](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/building-dlls-with-mingw/)
another examle why [WINDOWS](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?522508-Subsystem-Windows)

**exe:**
/SUBSYSTEM and /ENTRY should be set explicitly, if not set, linker will again automaticaly set the subsystem AND entry point as noted in the link above.

so to answer my original question, none of the above "stupid" macros must be defined :)